# Prerender + AngularJS +Apache

Tags: angularjs, prerender

The basics:

```
    -index.html
         <meta name="fragment" content="!">
         <base href="/index.html">
         <script> window.prerenderReady = false; </script>
    -app.js
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    .htaccess
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "token"
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://example.org/$2 [P,L]
       </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

Each time I try visiting the link using the service or my local prerender server, I see an empty page. All the elements from index.html are there, but they are not rendered. Any ideas would be great

Comment: Can you send the URL you are testing to support@prerender.io so we can look into it? You have the prerender config copy/pasted twice in your config there so you should probably remove one of those. Also, you still have http://example.org/ in the config which you'll want to remove and use your website instead.

Comment: @Prerender.io I'll take out the second ifmodule, yeah I was just taking them out for security